# How add to collection only models with no record joined - Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, join, laravel-5, eloquent

In my model `Questions` I have simple relation to `Standpoint`

```
public function standpoints_byrel()
{
//    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Standpoint');
return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Standpoint',  'question_id');

}
```

Now,
I have yet another model `Userattitude (table`user_attitudes`) which allow users to upvote and downvote Standpoints.

I am able to list Standpoints, which were voted by a given user:

```
    $user_attitudes = Userattitude::join('entitystandpoints', function ($q) use($questionid,$user) {
        $q->where('user_attitudes.item_type', '=', 'entitystandpoint');
        $q->on('user_attitudes.item_id', '=', 'entitystandpoints.id');
        $q->where('entitystandpoints.question_id', '=', $questionid);
        $q->where('user_attitudes.creator_id','=', $user);
    })
    ->select('user_attitudes.*')
    ->get();
```

### TO DO

Now I try to list all standpoints, which were NOT voted by the given user. 
I have no idea how to do it using Eloquent. 
Any help appreciated.

#### edit

condition to meet:
if an user votes up or down, a new model Userattitude is created. Therefore Standpoint models not down- or upvoted have nothing to join. still, in the Userattitude there are two fields for upvoting : 'attitude' and 'importance'. often one of them is null

Comment: Sorry I wrote an answer but then I realized: what is the condition "which were voted by a given user" ? I assumed it is the existence of an element in the entitystandpoints table, but let me know if this is the case...

Comment: oh, sorry. if an user votes up or down, a new model Userattitude is created. Therefore Standpoint models not down- or upvoted have nothing to join. still, in the Userattitude there are two fields for upvoting : 'attitude' and 'importance'. often one of them is `null`.

Comment: So the answer doesn't make much sense, as the left join is ignoring the left part of a join, in this case entitystandpoints. But your case seem to be the contrary. Anyway, you're not listing the standpoints as you said in the queston, but the user_attitudes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with a left join where the left parameter of the join is null.
Something like this (but please check the syntax out, I'm not an Eloquent expert):

```
   $user_attitudes = Userattitude::leftJoin('entitystandpoints', function ($q) use($questionid,$user) {
        $q->where('user_attitudes.item_type', '=', 'entitystandpoint');
        $q->on('user_attitudes.item_id', '=', 'entitystandpoints.id');
        $q->where('entitystandpoints.question_id', '=', $questionid);
        $q->where('user_attitudes.creator_id','=', $user);
    })
    ->whereNull('entitystandpoints.id')
    ->select('user_attitudes.*')
    ->get();
```

Let me know.